# Lines in a rectangle with a specific point $P$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

[image]

I came across this interesting problem that might teach me something new.

On the above diagram, $ABCD$ is a rectangle and point $P$ such that $PB = 4\sqrt{2}$, $PC = 4$ and $PD= 3$.

Our goal is to find $PA$. If this was a problem that has good description I would just search up it, however, this is not easy to describe to a search engine, so here's my *actual* question: How do you find a length of a given line that is in a rectangle connected to some point inside the rectangle and knowing how long each of the other lines connecting the rectangle's corner with the specific point? (Hopefully you didn't have a headache reading this)

I suspect there is some sort of formula to figure this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the value of $x$ in $ABCD$ rectangle where $AE = 4, BE = 6, CE=5$ and $DE = x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094476/what-is-the-value-of-x-in-abcd-rectangle-where-ae-4-be-6-ce-5-and-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hint

Draw parallel lines from point $P$ to the all four sides of the rectangle. Apply the Pythagorean Theorem four times and solve the system of equations.

> You should obtain: $PB^2+PD^2=PA^2+PC^2$

Comment: That was brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: This theorem is known as the British Flag theorem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, never heard the name of this wonderful theorem. This is such a powerful theorem that it remains true when $P$ is on a side or outside the rectangle, and even when $P$ is not coplanar with the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's draw 4 perpendecular lines on all four edges from point P. The lines meet the edges at points L, R, U, D. I will call the heights: $h_{L}$,  $h_{R}$, $h_{U}$, $h_{D}$

$$   PB^2 - PL^2 = LB^2 = CR^2 = CP^2 - PR^2    $$
Thus:
$$ 32 - 16 = PL^2 - PR^2   $$

Similarly:

$$ PA^2 - PD^2 = ...= PL^2 - PR^2 $$

Thus, according to the two previous equations:
$$ PA^2 - 9 =  16 $$
$$PA = 5$$